# Navigating series of files in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

When modifying code I find I often have to go through dozens of files to change the simplest of things. For example lets say I have a function `pretty_print` and I change it to conform to camel case `prettyPrint`. Now I want to go through the files `apple1.js` to `apple99.js`, and possibly a few `orange.js` files in there. Is there a quick way to do this in Vim?

NOTE: this is not something I can automate, I actually need to go in and modify the code myself.

I know I can do `:b <fileName>`, but, although it supports name completion/pattern matching, I don't think the pattern is carried over.

For example, if I do

```
:b apple*.js
```

and I hit tab, I'll get

```
:b apple1.js
```

but if I revisit that function (either by pressing `:` + upArrow or `q:`) then if I hit tab it won't go to

```
:b apple2.js
```

What I want is to specify something like

```
:b apple*.js
```

edit the file, then when I type `:w`, it moves to the next buffer. I would prefer to stay in Vim, I don't want to come out, type `vim apple*.js`, go back into Vim and then use the `:x` command. I realize this works, but I still need all the other files in case I want to, for example jump between tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most suitable solution for you in this case would be to use the
grep capabilities integrated in Vim.  The following command performs a search
for the pattern `\<pretty_print\>` in files matching the wildcard `apple*.js`,
and stores locations of the pattern's occurrences in the quickfix list
allowing to easily jump through all the matches.

```
:vimgrep /\<pretty_print\>/ apple*.js
```

For more detailed introduction into the quickfix list with regard to searching
in files, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870139/loading-a-set-of-files-obtained-via-cmd-exec-into-vim-buffers/6870257#6870257) to the question "[Loading a set of files obtained
via cmd-exec into Vim buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870139/loading-a-set-of-files-obtained-via-cmd-exec-into-vim-buffers)".

If you would like to simply open a list of files matching a particular
wildcard, load that files' names into the argument list

```
:args apple*.js
```

and then navigate between them using `:n` and `:N`, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

start with this:

```
:set hidden "required because `argdo` won't load next argument into current window
            "if there is a modified buffer displayed inside this window
:args apple*.js
:argdo %s/\<pretty_print\>/prettyPrint/g
:rewind " if you want to proofread all files then use :next and :prev
:wa
```

You better version your files and do a diff after such a change.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [BufSel](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) function from Wikia matches your needs?

> If you would prefer to be able to select the buffer **from the list of
>   partial matches** the following function can be used. It will jump to
>   the matching buffer if only one match is found, or if there are many
>   matches it will print a list of the matching buffers in the
>   command-line area, and allow you to select one of the matching buffers
>   by buffer number.

```
function! BufSel(pattern)
  let bufcount = bufnr("$")
  let currbufnr = 1
  let nummatches = 0
  let firstmatchingbufnr = 0
  while currbufnr <= bufcount
    if(bufexists(currbufnr))
      let currbufname = bufname(currbufnr)
      if(match(currbufname, a:pattern) > -1)
        echo currbufnr . ": ". bufname(currbufnr)
        let nummatches += 1
        let firstmatchingbufnr = currbufnr
      endif
    endif
    let currbufnr = currbufnr + 1
  endwhile
  if(nummatches == 1)
    execute ":buffer ". firstmatchingbufnr
  elseif(nummatches > 1)
    let desiredbufnr = input("Enter buffer number: ")
    if(strlen(desiredbufnr) != 0)
      execute ":buffer ". desiredbufnr
    endif
  else
    echo "No matching buffers"
  endif
endfunction

"Bind the BufSel() function to a user-command
command! -nargs=1 Bs :call BufSel("<args>")
```

Comment: I actually installed BufSel and used it at first, but then gave up, I wonder if it does what I want here. In any case, it was not much of an improvement over `:b` and it just turned out to be so much easier to close vim, and restart it with only the files I wanted to edit.